# R: Row wise operation on same column to produce N more columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to come up with multiple columns based on a column (path) in data table. My dataset is currently 6 millions rows.

**EDIT: Included minimal dataset which is naive**

```
set.seed(24);
DATA <- data.frame(path=paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 25, replace=TRUE),">",sample(LETTERS[1:3], 25, replace=TRUE)), value=rnorm(25))
```

Following is code that I'm currently using (of course I'm not grepl'ing alphabets):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DATA)) {
  if(grepl("A", DATA$path[i])){DATA$A[i]=1}else{DATA$A[i]=0}
  if(grepl("B", DATA$path[i])){DATA$B[i]=1}else{DATA$B[i]=0}
  if(grepl("C", DATA$path[i])){DATA$C[i]=1}else{DATA$C[i]=0}
}
```

An older version of the code I was using is:

```
DATA$A <- sapply(DATA$path, function(x) { if(grepl("A", x)){1}else{0}})
DATA$B <- sapply(DATA$path, function(x) { if(grepl("B", x)){1}else{0}})
```

for every column that I want to output.

but this is very inefficient as it sapply too many times.

My question is: is there a more efficient way to do the same thing? or am I stuck with the first code chunk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many columns do you have to input? more than 4/5 ?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Yes I need more than 4/5 columns, possibly 10 or more, depending on Path content.

Comment: @akrun I have added sample data based on your example, which I think slightly clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `split` the 'path' column with `>` and get the `unique` elements in that column ('Un1').  Loop over 'Un1' and use `grepl` to find the match.

```
Un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(DATA$path), '>'))))
DATA[Un1] <- lapply(Un1, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, DATA$path)))
```

Or another option is using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` on the `strsplit` output, negate (`!`) to convert `0` to 'TRUE' and all other values to 'FALSE', negate again so that 'FALSE' becomes 'TRUE' and viceversa, wrap it with `+(` to coerce the logical to integer.  We can also use `as.integer` or `+0L` etc for this.

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(DATA, +(!!mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(DATA$path), '>')) ))
```

Or after splitting the 'path' column, we can loop over the columns, apply `model.matrix` and use `|` with `Reduce`

```
 d1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,strsplit(as.character(DATA$path), '>'))
 names(d1) <- paste0('path', 1:2)
 cbind(DATA, +(Reduce(`|`,lapply(d1, function(x) model.matrix(~0+x)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
DATA$A = grepl('A', DATA$path) + 0L
```

Comment: this is usable as well, but I'm looking for a more concise solution where it doesn't involve going through the entire dataset N (number of columns I need to create) times.